# COVID 19 feed with incidences and Geo Points

Tags: covid-19, covid-19-datasets

I am looking for a maintained and updated data feed that has the times of all confirmed cases of COVID 19 and their Geo coordinates. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.arcgis.com/apps/opsdashboard/index.html#/bda7594740fd40299423467b48e9ecf6

> We are tracking the COVID-19 spread in real-time on our interactive dashboard with data available for download. We are also modeling the spread of the virus. Preliminary study results are discussed on our blog.

This is by the John Hopkins University.